# puppeteer: how to pass a variable to page.type method?

Tags: puppeteer

I've created the variable randomSixNum whose result is 6 random numbers and i want to pass it to puppeteers page.type method.

```
    ***let randomSixNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*89999+100000);
    await page.type('#developer-name', randomSixNum)***
```

The issue i am having is that i keep getting the error ( Type Error: text is not iterable)

I know that randomSixNum definitely returns 6 random numbers, so my suspicion is that the page.type method doesn't accept numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. Converting `randomSixNum` to a string fixes the issue.

```
let randomSixNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*89999+100000);
await page.type('#developer-name', randomSixNum.toString());
```